# mysql multiple limit in one sql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have table in my DB called "students" contains the following columns
 (student_id, student_name, year_of_birth).and array of years
I trying to make one query that gets 10 student_id of each year in (years) array.

I could write

```
SELECT student_id FROM `students` WHERE year_of_birth=1950 LIMIT 10;
SELECT student_id FROM `students` WHERE year_of_birth=1951 LIMIT 10;
SELECT student_id FROM `students` WHERE year_of_birth=1952 LIMIT 10;
SELECT student_id FROM `students` WHERE year_of_birth=1953 LIMIT 10;
(and so on)
```

But that would be very time consuming
Are there any other options
Thank you

Answer (score 7):

"select N rows for a group in MySQL" : http://explainextended.com/2009/03/06/advanced-row-sampling/

Answer (score 2):

If you concern is that the queries will return multiple result sets, you could throw a `UNION ALL` in between each `SELECT`:

```
SELECT student_id FROM `students` WHERE year_of_birth=1950 LIMIT 10
UNION ALL
SELECT student_id FROM `students` WHERE year_of_birth=1951 LIMIT 10
UNION ALL
...
```

This can of course be combined with alexn's approach of generating the query from an array of years.

I do *not* think this will give you much better performance than seperate queries, but it might (in a future version of MySQL) since it gives the database engine a little more information about what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub-query that links back to the table:

```
SELECT student_id FROM `students` AS s1
WHERE student_id IN 
  (SELECT s2.student_id FROM `students` AS s2
     WHERE s1.year_of_birth = s2.year_of_birth
     LIMIT 10)
```

Only one problem though: this will only work if you use MySQL 5.1 or higher.

The alternative is to use a union statement:

```
for ($year = 1950; $year < 2000; $year++) {
  $stmts[] = "SELECT student_id FROM `students` 
                WHERE year_of_birth = $year LIMIT 10";
}
$sql = implode(' UNION ALL ', $stmts;
```

This will work for a wider range of MySQL versions.

Answer (score 1):

This is also one of the example to find leap year with multiple limits

```
select year_n from the_years

select distinct month_n from the_months,the_years where year_n=$P{Year}

(select distinct day_n from the_days,the_months where $P{Month} IN('Jan','Mar','May','Jul','Aug','Oct','Dec') limit 31)
UNION ALL
(select distinct day_n from the_days,the_months where $P{Month} IN('Apr','Jun','Sep','Nov') limit 30)
UNION ALL
(select distinct day_n from the_days,the_years,the_months where $P{Month}='Feb' and mod($P{Year},4)!=0 or mod($P{Year},100)=0  or mod($P{Year},400)=0  limit 28)
UNION ALL
(select distinct day_n from the_days,the_years,the_months where $P{Month}='Feb' and mod($P{Year},4)=0 and mod($P{Year},100)!=0 or mod($P{Year},400)=0 limit 29)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not simply do that:

```
$studentIds = array(1950, 1951, 1952, 1953);

$sql = "
   SELECT
        student_id,
        year_of_birth
    FROM
        students
    WHERE
        student_id IN (" . implode(',', $studentIds) . ")
";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$students = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $students[$row['year_of_birth']] = $row['student_id'];
}
```

Your `$students` array will contain arrays of student ids with the keys as the years of birth.

Comment: if you're more concerned about the limit, you can limit it in php, with a counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
SELECT first.*
    from (
    SELECT student_id FROM students WHERE year_of_birth=1950 LIMIT 0,10
    ) AS first
    UNION 
    SELECT second.*
    from 
    (
    SELECT student_id FROM `students` WHERE year_of_birth=1951 LIMIT 10;
    )as second
```